# How to add onClick on the component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using https://github.com/winhtaikaung/react-tiny-link for displaying some posts from other blogs. I am able to get the previews correctly. I want to capture the views count through onClick() but this module(react-tiny-link) doesn't seems to support the same, please help.

```
<ReactTinyLink
cardSize="large"
showGraphic={true}
maxLine={0}
minLine={0}
header={""}
description={""}
url={url}
onClick={() => this.handleViewCount(id)} />
```

I tried adding div around the component but it affects the css.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code where you are using an `onClick` callback.

Comment: Added the component code here.

Comment: Wrapping with `onClick` handler is correct answer, but how is the `<div />` affecting CSS? This library is rendering content into `<a />` which have `display: flex` on them, but a `<div />` by default is `display: block`.

Comment: Hi @Sauravkumar thanks for using `react-tiny-link`,I am the author of this lib  please upgrade your `react-tiny-link` Version 3.4.0 to have `onClick` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your link with a `div` and attach your `onClick` callback on that `div` instead.

```
<div onClick={() => this.handleViewCount(id)}>
  <ReactTinyLink
    cardSize="large"
    showGraphic={true}
    maxLine={0}
    minLine={0}
    header={""}
    description={""}
    url={url}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

Your library - ReactTinyLink does not support onClick attribute.
Since you've tagged javascript - I can give you a small JS hack for the same.

Run the following code at the end of your React Rendering

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('react_tinylink_card');
linksClicked = [];

for(var i = 0; i<cards.length; i++){
    cards[i].onclick = function(){
        linksClicked.push(this.href);
    }
}
```

The above code will go through each and every cards and will attach onClick handlers on them, once clicked - the **'this'** object will be your anchor tag's element, so I am storing it's href. (you're free to store anything you want)

In the following example - https://winhtaikaung.github.io/react-tiny-link/
I tried the same snippet - and got the following result
[image]

Hope this would be a good starting point for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @abhijat_saxena thanks for providing the workaround for `react-tiny-link`,I am the author of this lib btw. Please upgrade your `react-tiny-link` Version 3.4.0 to have `onClick` event. Let me know if you still have issue on adding `onClick` event